# C - Unable to free doubly linked list node

Tags: c, free, doubly-linked-list

I have data structure like this:

```
typedef struct telephoneBookNode
{
    int id;
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];
    char telephone[TELEPHONE_LENGTH];
    struct telephoneBookNode * previousNode;
    struct telephoneBookNode * nextNode;
} TelephoneBookNode;

typedef struct telephoneBookList
{
    TelephoneBookNode * head;
    TelephoneBookNode * tail;
    TelephoneBookNode * current;
    unsigned size;
} TelephoneBookList;
```

I can create Nodes, and make the List containing data because I got no problems in displaying the List, inserting or moving Nodes....

But when I write function to erase the List, I got error:

```
PhoneBook(6187,0x7fff77045000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f87c1f00004: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

This is my eraser functions:

```
void freeTelephoneBookList(TelephoneBookList* aList) {
    TelephoneBookNode* node;
    TelephoneBookNode* temp = aList->head;

    while (temp) {
        node = temp;
        temp = node->nextNode;
        freeTelephoneBookNode(node);
    }
    free(aList);
}

void freeTelephoneBookNode(TelephoneBookNode * node) {
    free(node->name);
    free(node->telephone);
    free(node);
}
```

Please anyone tells me what I have been doing wrong here. Thank you!

Comment: To free a single node, you must pass the address of the node to account for a deletion of the first node. e.g. `void freeTelephoneBookNode(TelephoneBookNode **node)`. You must rewire all next/prev pointers and if the first node is deleted, update the list address to the new first node.

Comment: The pointer you're passing to `freeTelephoneBookList` - where did it come from ? You have *some* of what is needed here for a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), just finish it off with a `main()` and whatever else is required exercise your code to the point of failure you claim. We're not mind readers, and I suspect your claim of "I got no problems..." isn't entirely accurate. *"... that I know of"* would probably be more so. Edit: Well, that function just *completely* changed, so now I got nothing.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That's not true. It doesn't matter if next/prev pointers in a node or first/last pointers in a list are zeroed at the moment the node or the list object is being deleted, What is important is if they are retained long enough in an additional variable to let next/prev node to be deleted. And they are.

Comment: Errr, I mean the were before OF rewrote the question to some completely different code.  Now I can't tell what code is discussed here – an initial version, the current one, ore some future modification....?

Comment: How do you expect to get a meaningful answer, if you change the code BEFORE one can finish writing an answer?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you are freeing the entire list, is surely does matter if you are freeing a single-node...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Right, but the question is (was...?) about erasing the whole list, not removing a single node from it.

Comment: I am sorry, because I was also trying to fix the code then updated my post but I don't know that makes the readers confused.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code is morphing as contributors assemble answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE** This anwer relates to the [**initial version**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37502664/1) of the question.

Variables `node->name` and `node->telephone` are **not** pointers to separate allocated blocks of memory, they're just parts of `*node`. Reduce the `freeTelephoneBookNode` function to

```
void freeTelephoneBookNode(TelephoneBookNode * node) {
    free(node);
}
```

Comment: when I change this function like that, the program got crashed with out an error displayed. Then I tried fixing the code and update my post. I have written printf("1") in `if` block, and printf("2") in `else` block, I got this sequence when it runs: 222222222222222222211. So when it erases the list to the last node, it got crashed.

Comment: @LKPhucNguyen 1. Your code does not contain any `if` or `else` blocks. If you want to discuss another piece of code, please post another question. 2. Your `freeTelephoneBookList` is IMHO correct, the error with `free`–ing a 'not allocated block' certainly *can* arise in `freeTelephoneBookNode`, and I gave a solution above. 3. If you get another error, it's probably due to inconsistency in your data. You need either to diagnose it better or post a new question with a complete code. See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)